# I was trouble bubble value in highcharts .How to show by default value in series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was trouble bubble value in highcharts .How to show by default value in series

I want show by default value in bubble. when i was hovered in bubble showing series value but i want to show by default series value is this possible.?

https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/q734jr5t/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
},

series: [{
    data: [
        [9, 81, 63],
        [98, 5, 89],
        [51, 50, 73],
        [41, 22, 14],
        [58, 24, 20],
        [78, 37, 34],
        [55, 56, 53],
        [18, 45, 70],
        [42, 44, 28],
        [3, 52, 59],
        [31, 18, 97],
        [79, 91, 63],
        [93, 23, 23],
        [44, 83, 22]
    ],
    marker: {
        fillColor: {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')]
            ]
        }
    }
}, ]

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add plot options in chart with datalables

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/668xwtsm/5/)

```
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x:40,/*shifting values to right side*/
            format: '({point.x},{point.y})<br>Size:{point.z}'
        },
    }
},
```

Comment: i want same like when i hovered showing some value. i want exactly by default series value

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: can we add some CSS because i want exactly same like when i was hovered

Comment: can we possible to change the value beside of bubble

Comment: i am not getting can you post image what you want .yes i can it is not looking good at all

Comment: this is okay but i want values right side of the box don't want inside of the box

Comment: are you getting my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136418/discussion-between-kondal-and-deep-3015).